# replace new line characters in between entries in a tab separated file

Tags: shell, gawk

I have tab separated file which has field names like below

```
job_id  client_name shop_name   job_text   job_code  
 1      client1      shop1      job txt      0178923
 2      client2      shop2      "job2 txt    67676
                                job2-txt
                                job2_txt"
 3     client3      shop3       job3 txt     7878
```

under job_txt field the data will have new line charcters like above

```
 gawk -F\\t 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";}{ print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5;}' downloads/download.csv > common.csv
```

when i execute the above code , out put on common.csv of first field is like below

```
cut -f1 common.csv | head

job_id
 1
 2
 "job2 txt
 job2_txt
 job2 txt"
```

can someone help me on this

Comment: when runs your codes; everything works correctly; field 1 only prints job_id,1, 2 and 3.  I tested this GNU Awk 4.0.1 and cut (GNU coreutils) 8.21

Comment: What's your expected output?